# Playing mp3 file (size greater than 2Mb) from url throwing error 413

Tags: blackberry

I have a url of mp3 file. I want to play it using Player(javax.microedition.media.Player) without downloading the mp3 file to SD card. When i tried the following code , its throwing error 413- Requested entity too large.

```
  String httpURL1="http://www.example.com/song.mp3";
  Player player;
  player =Manager.createPlayer(httpURL1);
  player.realize();
  player.prefetch();
  player.start();
```

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: You can download the file first, then play it from local directory. I saw your previous question regarding almost same topic here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467348/get-data-from-url-in-blackberry. I think the answer of that question can be used in this case also.

Answer (score 1):

413 (Request entity Too Large) is an HTTP error returned by the BES or BIS when you try to transport a large file over it.

Check the following links:

[What Is - HTTP 413 Request Entity Too Large (DB-00623)](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/HTTP-413-Request-Entity-Too-Large/ta-p/445983)

[How To - Download large files using the BlackBerry Mobile Data System (DB-00619)](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Download-large-files-using-the-BlackBerry-Mobile-Data-System/ta-p/445858)

This limit is there to prevent excessive traffic being routed through RIM's infrastructure, or a corporate BES (In BES you can ask the BES admin to increase the max size to some extent, but this is not a solution for larger files, or if BES is not under your control). But you can always open the connection in direct TCP mode, or through Wi-Fi, and you'll be fine.

I posted a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9737006/813951).

Comment: this will download file to memory card and play na. i dot want that. First read my question.

Comment: I was updating my answer. Gimme a break! :)

Answer (score -1):

To Play a Mp3 file without saving it to SD Card create player in

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            try
            {
                _player = Manager.createPlayer(url);
                _player.realize();*/
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Dialog.alert("Streaming player is not intialized due to network failure !");
                //Dialog.alert("Error is " + ex.toString());
            }       
        }
    });
_player.start();
```

Create and realize it in to UI thread rather than in main Thread.

Also to determine the Network layer , refer this link to add in httpURL1

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Different-ways-to-make-an-HTTP-or-socket-connection/ta-p/445879

Comment: its going to the catch block.

Comment: Http connection or stream connection ?

Comment: its also throwing same result. 413

Comment: Live Streaming wont work in Simulator, Check it in Real device.